# Trying to create dynamic ES Index facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.spel.ExpressionDependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Using <spring-boot.version>2.3.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
added following dependencies :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Trying to create dynamic ES Index

```
@Document(indexName = "test_#{@commonConfig.getEnv()}_v1")
```

```java
@Component("commonConfig")
public class CommonConfig {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String env;

    public String getEnv() {
        return env.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot 2.3.x is no longer supported https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support the last release was 2.3.12 last summer.

In any case, Boot 2.3.x uses spring-data-commons 2.3.x (2.3.9 pulls in 2.3.7).

`ExpressionDependencies` was not added to spring-data-commons until 2.4, so you have some mismatched dependencies somehow.